# Program to run two motors with Motor driver

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm trying to make a program that would run two motors clockwise and then anticlockwise. But my program is causing my motors to only run clockwise everytime . It doesn't run anticlockwise at all. Can anyone help me find the bug?

Main code:

```
void loop()
{
  // turn on motor A
  digitalWrite(In1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(In2, LOW);
  // set speed to 150 out 255
  analogWrite(EnA, 150);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(In3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(In4, LOW);
  // set speed to 150 out 255
  analogWrite(EnB, 150);
  delay(2000);
   digitalWrite(In1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In2, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(In3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(In4, HIGH);
  // now turn off motors
  digitalWrite(In1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(In3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In4, LOW);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: How long is there between turning anti-clockwise and stopping the motors...?

Comment: I didn't set any delay between anticlockwise rotation.

Comment: Which means what...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this one

```
void loop()
{
  // turn on motor A
  digitalWrite(In1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(In2, LOW);
  // set speed to 150 out 255
  analogWrite(EnA, 150);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(In3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(In4, LOW);
  // set speed to 150 out 255
  analogWrite(EnB, 150);
  delay(2000);
   digitalWrite(In1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In2, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(In3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(In4, HIGH);
  // now turn off motors
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(In1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In2, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(In3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(In4, LOW);
  delay(2000);
}
```